# Expansion velocity and recessional velocity

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Differentiation of scale factors means the rate of expansion. But at the same time,

recession velocity has the following relationship: $\dot{}=\dot{}$

Do the recessional velocity and expansion velocity mean the same thing? (when co-moving distance is fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both mean the same velocity.